# Assert function in C++ using cassert function - How can I declare the variables in the test function?

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cassert>

using namespace std;

void test();

void test() { //my attempted test function in order to ensure the program works correctly

string answ1 = "noooooob";
string answ2 = "saaaaaadie";
string answ3 = "trish";

assert(answer(answ1) == "nob"); //this is where i get the compile error that "answer" not declared
assert(answer(answ2) == "sadie");
assert(answer(answ3) == "trish");

cout << "All test cases passed!" << endl;

}

int main() {

    int i = 0;
    string output;
    string input;
    char x;

    getline(cin, input); //input

    output += input[0];
    x = input[0];


    while (i < input.length()) {

        i++;
        if (input [i] != x) {
            output += input[i];
        }
        x = input[i];
    }

    cout << output << endl;

    test();

    return 0;
}
```

All I'm really asking is how to declare the "answer" variable in the assert function. Maybe I'm doing it completely wrong, and my apologies if so. I'm pretty new to the coding scene. Do I need to make a string that would loop through the current for loop in my main function? Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: First of all, header files are *not* "libraries". Libraries can have header file, and there are some header-only libraries which only have header files, but they are still header files and not often called "library".

Comment: What do you want `answer` to mean?  You call it a variable, but you are using it like a function.  (or possibly a constructor) Put another way -- what are you actually trying to _test_?

Comment: Secondly, [`assert`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/assert) is a macro, which is typically disabled in release-type builds. One should never use `assert` for validation outside of debugging. Also, `assert` will crash the program, which isn't very user-friendly.

Comment: I strongly recommend going with a unit test framework such as Google Test or the Boost unit test framework instead of the assert macro. This would allow you to execute the tests in non-debug configurations in addition to providing non-compiler dependent output.

Comment: If `answer` is a variable, it's of class type and have a member function looking like `something operator()(string)` or similar. Is that the case?

Comment: And `answer(answ1)` makes no sense, especially as part of an assert. What is it even supposed to mean? What is `answer`?

Comment: @fabian I appreciate the feedback. Like I said, I'm new to this, so debugging is a little difficult when you are unsure of what to debug.

Comment: Perhaps you meant to write a function `std:::string answer(std::string input)` which, when given a string condenses consecutive duplicate letters. Then you could call that function in `main`, and you could also call that function in `test`.

Comment: @NathanPierson This is extremely helpful, and addressed the question I asked. Thank you.

Comment: @NathanPierson What would be in that `std : : string answer(std : : string input)` function? The same thing I have written? That's still something I'm unsure of.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Either you forgot to include a header where you define a class or a function with name `answer`
2. or you don't need it and just comapre strings:

```
assert(answ1 == "nob"); // operator== kicks in
assert(answ2 == "sadie");
assert(answ3 == "trish");
```

---

You should be aware that `assert` is a debug-only feature. It compiles to nothing in release mode.
You should probably reevaluate your approach for unit testing as the comments suggest (GTest would be fine).